# What's the "value" property in Binding tag?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

I have a rookie question, but I couldn't find an answer for that. I'm not even sure how to ask google that question.

Let's say you have:

```
Tag="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type StackPanel}, AncestorLevel=2}}"
```

How to do it this way?:

```
<Button.Tag>
    <Binding ??? RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type StackPanel}, AncestorLevel=2}" />
</Button.Tag>
```

I've tried "Content" "Value" "Source".. Thanks for help!

Comment: `Tag` is essentially a property of `Button` control. So why not do it the first way?

Comment: If you must you can have a `ContentControl` inside the `Tag` and do this, but I really don't see why you would want to:             `<Button.Tag>
                <ContentControl>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ...}"/>
                </ContentControl>
            </Button.Tag>`

Comment: Why not just do <Button tag = Your binding stuff> </Button> ? No real reason to try and do it the second way.

Comment: @Sach "tag" is also a HTML word for `Binding` `Button` or any.. tag. In Html you have `HTML` tag, `BODY` tag, `<P>` tag etc

Comment: @robertwojnar A HTML or XML or XAML tag is just a syntactical element, i.e. an identifier enclosed in angle brackets. It has nothing to do with data binding and is also entirely unrelated to the [FrameworkElement.Tag Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Button ...>
    <Button.Tag>
        <Binding .../>
    </Button.Tag>
</Button>
```

is equivalent to

```
<Button Tag="{Binding ...}" />
```

However, you are missing the Binding's source property path. Add `Path="DataContext"`:

```
<Button.Tag>
    <Binding Path="DataContext" .../>
</Button.Tag>
```